# Phoenix Framework: Maliciously Reusing Session Cookie To Access Website

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

For starters, I am currently setting a `Plug.Session` as follows:

```
plug Plug.Session,
    store: :cookie,
    key: "_key",
    signing_salt: "SALT_HERE"
```

When the user logs out they hit:

```
def logout(conn, _) do
    conn
    |> configure_session(drop: true)
    |> redirect(to: "/login")
  end
```

All login/logout features work and a new `_key` is generated back on the login form. The issue I'm having is if I copy the value of the `_key` while I'm logged in, and replace the cookie value in the browser via Chrome Debugger when I'm logged out, I'm able to navigate to a direct GET URL without logging in and then can access everything as if I logged in.

Is there a good way to combat this? I realize that it would be incredibly difficult to get the `_key` value of someone logged in and use it before they log in again and generate a new one but after browsing around a bit I wasn't able to find anything about this.

Answer (score 3):

The way to combat this would be to move session storage from cookie to server side. When you have `store: :cookie` all session information is stored on the user's machine IN the cookie. It's encrypted with a key that lives on the server. That `|> configure_session(drop: true)` just clears that user's cookie. If you change session storage to ets or redis on the server side, the user's cookie only contains a key that references session data stored on the server, giving you full control to invalidate the session.

Example package that can help you with this: https://github.com/thoughtbot/redbird